# ClickOnce hash failures when using code contract rewriter

Tags: validation, hash, clickonce, manifest, code-contracts

I am creating a ClickOnce deployment.

Now, I am using CodeContracts rewriter, which means that the application manifest is generated **before** CodeContracts modifies my assembly.

Therefore, I update the application manifest file with an up-to-date hash and file size. Here's the algorithm to compute the hash:

```
    public static string ComputeHash(FileInfo info)
    {
        SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] hashBytes = sha1.ComputeHash(info.OpenRead());
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
    }
```

I then save the manifest. I then update the ClickOnce deployment manifest (.application) which has a hash and size for the application manifest using the same hash computation routine.

After this, I run a test program which tells me that **all** the hashes and file sizes match those of the real files on disk.

Yet when I run the ClickOnce deployment it **always** complains that the hash verification failed for the main .exe file (which is the only dependent assembly in the application manifest that needs changing).

Note that if I do not change the hashes and sizes myself, the ClickOnce also fails because the information is even more palpably wrong (the file size is different, not just the hash).

Is there anyway I can see why the hash validation is failing when I think it is valid?

Or better still, is there a way I can generate manifests after the code contracts rewriter has finished hacking my executables?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Mage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to update and resign your manifests? Look at the Update (-u) and the Sign (-s) commands.

Comment: I don't sign the manifest at the moment so that's not an issue. I'd really rather avoid using Mage, as I want to use the API directly in a build activity.

Comment: Also, I have tried calling the ApplicationManifest.UpdateFileInfo() method in code, and it does not fix broken file hashes and sizes.

Comment: Did you try a `ResolveFiles()` call before the `UpdateFileInfo()`?